# Combine mouseover with specific class id addition on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm asking for help because I can't fix this javascript as I would like. Basically I would like to add the class "typewriter" to the id "textanimation" on mouseover then remove it.

The rest works, in the sense that I correctly buy the div with the descriptive text and the photo. Thanks for all the suggestions

https://codepen.io/bastia-g5/pen/LYgPGNp

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').hover(function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("textanimation");
            element.classList.add("typewriter");
        $('#d'+$(this).prop('id')).show();
    }, function() {
        var element = document.getElementById("textanimation");
            element.classList.remove("typewriter");
        $('#d'+$(this).prop('id')).hide();
    });
    
});
```

```css
.first {
 display:none;    
}

.hover_img {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sectionhome">
    <div class="row verticalalign">
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <h1 id="firstdiv">Brand</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="hover_img" id="dfirstdiv">
                <p id="textanimation" class="subtitle">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
            </div>
      
      <div>
                <h1 id="seconddiv">Servizi</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="hover_img" id="dseconddiv">
                <p id="textanimation" class="subtitle">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
            </div>
      
      <div>
                <h1 id="thirddiv">B2B</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="hover_img" id="dthirddiv">
                <p id="textanimation" class="subtitle">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
            </div>
      
      
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You don't want to have duplicate HTML IDs, in your case `#textanimation`. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you have multiple elements with the ID `textanimation`, but HTML IDs must be unique. This means that `var element = document.getElementById("textanimation");` always returns the first element with that ID. Instead, use a class to select the desired element and use jQuery's `.find` to confine your search to children of the `<div>` that is being shown:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').hover(function() {    
    const id = $(this).attr('id');
    const containerId = `d${id}`;
    
    $(`#${containerId}`)
      .show()
      .find('.subtitle').toggleClass('typewriter', true)
    ;
  }, function() {
    const id = $(this).attr('id');
    const containerId = `d${id}`;
    
    $(`#${containerId}`)
      .hide()
      .find('.subtitle').toggleClass('typewriter', false)
    ;
  });
});
```

```css
.first {
  display: none;
}

.hover_img {
  display: none;
}

.typewriter {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sectionhome">
  <div class="row verticalalign">
    <div class="col">
      <div>
        <h1 id="firstdiv">Brand</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hover_img" id="dfirstdiv">
        <p id="textanimation" class="subtitle">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1 id="seconddiv">Servizi</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hover_img" id="dseconddiv">
        <p id="textanimation" class="subtitle">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1 id="thirddiv">B2B</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="hover_img" id="dthirddiv">
        <p id="textanimation" class="subtitle">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```